# Assignment of address to a pointer-to-pointer gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, function-pointers

I have a binary search tree class, BSTree. It used to have a single member, a root node for the tree. The type of a node is defined by the BSTNode struct.
But then i added another member, a pointer to a function that is used to compare two elements. That's when problems started.

Interface:

```
template <typename T>
struct BSTNode {
public:
    struct BSTNode<T> *left;
    struct BSTNode<T> *right;
    T key;
    BSTNode<T>(T element){ key = element;}
};

template <typename T>
class BSTree {
private:
    BSTNode<T> *root;
    int (*compare)(T el1, T el2); // this is the new member
public:
BSTree<T>(int (*cmp)(T el1, T el2)) {root = NULL; compare = cmp;}
    //...
```

The function BSTree::add, which adds stuff to the tree, uses a pointer to the pointer to the root node. This function broke after i added the new 'compare' member. The function begins as follows (it has some printf lines i added to find the exact line that crashed):

Function Definition:

```
template <typename T>
BSTNode<T>* BSTree<T>::add(T element) {
    BSTNode<T> **node;
    printf("&root = %p\n", &root);
    printf("node = %p\n", node); //must be NULL
    printf("compare = %p\n", (int(*)(T, T))compare); //address stored in fn pointer
    node = &root; /////////// THIS PART produces the segmentation fault. ////////
    printf("succeeded");
    //...
```

Function Call (in main):

```
BSTree<int> bst(&stdcomp); //stdcomp is the integer compare function
bst.add(6);
//...
```

Output:

```
&root = 0x7fff5fbff8c0
node = 0x0
compare = 0x100001325
Segmentation fault
```

What is especially puzzling to me is that the assignment fails, even though it does not dereference the address that is stored in my pointer-to-pointer 'node', and 'node' is a local variable and is not being dereferenced; I don' know where the illegal memory access occur. I tried to initialize node to several literal values (e.g. NULL or 0x1), and they did not produce the error. It only failed after I added the function pointer to the class, which according to what is printed, is assigned the correct address. Does it have anything to do with misuse of templates?

By the way, the BSTree template is instantiated with typenames int and const char*, each with a different compare function that is correctly assigned (I think). I tested their add function and both produced the fault.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an overload of operator= that might be getting triggered?

Comment: nope. i didnt overload any operator and my classes dont have superclasses :S

Comment: Why do you have `BSTNode<T> **node`? I don't see why pointers-to-pointers are needed.

Comment: the pointer-to-pointer is to be able to modify nodes. This function adds stuff to the tree, it finds the appropiate leaf node with a null pointer, and changes the value of that pointer to the new node

Comment: Looks like your error lies elsewhere. I tested your code fragment and it works fine (clean run with valgrind, too).

Answer (score 1):

Your segmentation fault is proabably happening AFTER the `printf("succeeded");` call, as that printf doesn't include a newline, and your output is probably in line-buffered mode.  So the string 'succeeded' is going into the stdout buffer but doesn't appear on the screen.  Either put stdout into unbuffered mode, or stick a `\n` in the string.  Or better yet, stick `fflush(stdout);` after each printf so the buffer gets flushed regardless of the stdout buffering mode.

Comment: OR he can just use a debugger like anyone else. I don't see why he's printfing for something as simple as finding a segfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("compare = %p\n", (int(*)(T, T))compare);
```

This is undefined behavior - `printf`'s `%p` expects a pointer to `void`, but you pass a function pointer. Function pointers are not convertible to `void*`.

I recommend you to run your program in a debugger, to see it's really the assignment you suspect that's causing the fault. It might be some stack-smashing etc. The assignment itself should only invoke operations referencing the stack.

Comment: It turns out that function pointers are convertible to void on most architectures, but good point anyway. I'd still shudder if I saw one without an explicit cast. However, that looks like a pointer to member function which is definitely not convertible and may unbalance the stack.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's a horrible thing to do, sorry. It works in my arch, and it's a pointer to a non-member function, don't worry, i'm sure it's not a fat pointer -- yet I am well aware I'm not supposed to make these assumptions... The problem might be indeed related to the stack, since I'm almost sure it's the assignation to the local variable that crashes the program.

Comment: @user451963: Almost sure? Did you run it under the debugger? What is the exact instruction that's crashing and where is it in the disassembly of `add`?